# React Redux how to pass data from input to rest api

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to learn react redux and I creating a small todo app, which has backend as **REST server**

most of the part is implemented, however, I am not able to understand how to pass a value from my input box to rest API call.  I am able to successfully store the value of inputbox in redux state.

**I am using react-thunk as middleware to handle API calls.**

**container**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {toggleAddTodoDialog, addNewTodo, handleChange} from '../actions'
import AddTodoDialog from '../components/add_todo_dialog';
class AddTodoContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddTodoDialog toggleAddTodoDialog={this.props.toggleAddTodoDialog} 
                addNewTodo = {this.props.addNewTodo}
                newTodoList = {this.props.newTodoList}
                handleChange = {this.props.handleChange}
                is_add_todo_dialog_opened={this.props.is_add_todo_dialog_opened}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
}

const bindActionsToDispatch = dispatch => 
(
  {
    toggleAddTodoDialog : (e) => dispatch(toggleAddTodoDialog(e)),
    handleChange: (e) => dispatch(handleChange(e)),
    addNewTodo : (e) => addNewTodo(e)
  }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindActionsToDispatch)(AddTodoContainer)
```

**component**

```
export default class AddTodoDialog extends Component {

    toggleAddTodoDialog = (e) => {
        this.props.toggleAddTodoDialog(!this.props.is_add_todo_dialog_opened)
    }

    addNewTodo = (e) => {
        this.props.addNewTodo()
        this.toggleAddTodoDialog(e)
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.props.handleChange(e)    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggleAddTodoDialog}>Add new Todo</Button>
                <Modal isOpen={this.props.is_add_todo_dialog_opened} >
                    {/* <Modal isOpen={false} > */}
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleAddTodoDialog}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <FormGroup >
                            <Label for="Title">Task </Label>
                            <Input name="task"
                                value={this.props.newTodoList.task}
                                onChange={this.handleChange} />

                        </FormGroup>
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addNewTodo}>OK</Button>{' '}
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggleAddTodoDialog}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                </Modal>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

**actions**

```
export function addNewTodo() {
  console.log("addNewTodo")
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5001/todos", 'task=' + this.props.addNewTodo.task)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(_addTodoAction(response.data))
      })
  }
}

export function _addTodoAction(todos) {
  console.log("_addTodoAction")
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    todos: todos
  }
}

export function handleChange(event){
  console.log("handleChange "+event)
  return{
    type: 'HANDLE_CHANGE',
    event: event
  }
}
```

**reducer**

```
case 'ADD_TODO':
    console.log(action)
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: action.todos
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dispatching like this:

```
addNewTodo : (e) => addNewTodo(e)
```

But your action doesn't take any arguments:

```
export function addNewTodo() {
  console.log("addNewTodo")
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.post("http://localhost:5001/todos", 'task=' + this.props.addNewTodo.task)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(_addTodoAction(response.data))
      })
  }
}
```

If you want the value of the value of the input:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.props.handleChange(e.target.value)    
}
```

And then dispatch:

```
handleChange: (value) => dispatch(handleChange(value)),
```

And then in the action:

```
export function handleChange(value) {
...
```

Comment: I am passing the value to handleChange, I have updated to question. However when I try to access that state, I get an error in `addNewTodo()` action. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Comment: In your actions, you don't have access to props. Props are only for React components and actions is a simple js function. So you cannot do `axios.post("http://localhost:5001/todos", 'task=' + this.props.addNewTodo.task)`. You need to pass the value of task directly to the function.